# How to set a VB.NET/C# application title in Windows 7 jump list?

Tags: windows, winforms, title, jump-list

If we create a brand new Windows Forms Application project (say, using VB.NET), set it's AssemblyTitle attribute to something non-default like "WinApp1 Title", compile it and launch the WindowsApplication1.exe from the project bin\Release or bin\Debug subdirectory, we still see the default string "WindowsApplication1":

[image: WindowsApplication1]

This thing starts working as expected if we move the exe to another directory - say, to D:\Temp:

[image: WinApp1 Title]

The most funny thing happens if we create a shortcut to our exe and name it anyhow. No matter what exe is used - from bin\Debug or another custom folder, and no matter whether we launch the exe using the shortcut or double-click the exe itself in the Explorer. The jump list contains the name of the shortcut instead of the app title we specified:

[image: Shortcut's name]

The question is: how to set the unchangeable application title we need for the Win7/8 jump lists? Or is there any guide that describes how Windows determines the app tile in its jump lists?

Comment: Please try to make a cleanup and rebuild.

Comment: @Zicore, it does not help. Neither in VB nor in C#. And how it could help??!